# Django Tutorial Part 1: incorrect path causing (404)

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have setup part 1 of the django tutorial and am receiving the following 'Page not found (404)' error when trying to access the polls app:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AX8ai.png)

```
Page not found (404)
  Request Method:   GET
  Request URL:  http://proto.slc.venturedata.com/polls/
  Raised by:    polls.views.index

Using the URLconf defined in proto.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
  1. polls/
  2. admin/

The empty path didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

I'm using Django 2.2, Python 3.7, Apache 2.4.6, mod-wsgi 4.6.5.

I was able to complete the tutorial using the built in web server, but I started running into problems when I added Apache and mod-wsgi into the mix.  Here is my code:

proto/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
  path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

polls/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

polls/urls.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")
```

The only thing changed in the settings.py was the TIMEZONE. Everything else is set to defaults.

Something seems to be up with the urls and path matching.  The url I used (proto.slc.venturedata.com/polls/) should match the 'polls/' path, but the error message says that the path is empty.

In experimenting I found that I didn't receive an error if I modified proto/urls.py by replacing the 'polls/' path with an empty path: ''.

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('', include('polls.urls')),
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Am I missing something?

---

Including the non-default Apache configuration since the problems started after I configured Django to use Apache as the webserver.

```
ServerName 10.0.10.249:80
<Directory />
  AllowOverride none
  Require all denied
</Directory>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

WSGIPythonPath /var/local/www/proto/

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/local/www/proto"
    ServerName proto.slc.venturedata.com

    <Directory "/var/local/www/proto">
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias /polls /var/local/www/proto/proto/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Since the error happened when you moved to Apache, you should show your Apache configuration.

Comment: Can you show your html template?? I often get this error when I accidentally don't add the proper `{% url "app_name:function_name' %}`.

Comment: Daniel Roseman - I've include the Apache Configuration.  Saw my mistake as I was adding it to the post.  Thanks for the suggestion. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Daniel Roseman suggested I include my Apache configuration.  As I was adding the configuration parameters to this post I saw the error in the Virtual Host configuration.  WSGIScriptAlias is the culprit.

Current:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /polls /var/local/www/proto/proto/wsgi.py
```

Should Be:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/local/www/proto/proto/wsgi.py
```

After making the configuration change the tutorial is working as expected.

Sometimes it just takes someone looking over your shoulder.